# How to set static value in y-axis in chart.js?

Tags: chart.js

[Click here to view the Graph figure...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aRBfx.jpg)

Answer (score 12):

That would be a nice feature, but I don't think there is a direct way to do that. You could use the [afterBuildTicks](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#scales) call back in combination with the min, max, and autoSkip options.

## The Fix

The afterBuildTicks callback is passed the scale object. The scale object has an array of all the ticks to be displayed (stored in scale.ticks) so you could set your ticks in that array. Chart.js tries to make your chart look nice, so it will not show all the ticks by default. To fix this set the min and max to the lowest and highest values in your custom scale range. Also set autoSkip = false to make sure that all the ticks are displayed.

## Example

[jsfiddle with your example scale](https://jsfiddle.net/sj8jfn4q/)

[jsfiddle with a smaller scale range](https://jsfiddle.net/9a0cfae0/3/)

```
var ticks = [11000, 10000, 7000, 3000, 1000, 500, 100];
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"],
    datasets: [{
      data: [6000, 5000, 8000, 2000, 10000, 3500, 6000, 2000, 4000, 6000]
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          autoSkip: false,
          min: ticks[ticks.length - 1],
          max: ticks[0]
        },
        afterBuildTicks: function(scale) {
          scale.ticks = ticks;
          return;
        },
        beforeUpdate: function(oScale) {
          return;
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: @L Bahr Thanks for your answer bro. it helps for me!

Comment: Glad I could help. Can you mark this as the accepted answer since it answered your question

Comment: I'm sorry its helps, but it doesn't  the exactly answer to fix my chart, because when I set the value into million,thousand,hundred,ten the chart not good to look.
So as of now I used to not override the y-axis scale, Unfortunately my problem now is in risk when it they have million,thousand values.

Comment: The tick marks are places relative to their value based on the min and max tick values. That seems like the intuitive mechanic to have. What would you rather it do and why?

Comment: I agree that it is not useful, because the range is so large all the points look like a straight line. I thought that you wanted to see where the values are in the large range(the range from your example). What do you want the chart to look like?

Comment: Thanks, I was trying different options and this saved my day